# SUM columns by hour (using DATETIME column)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database that I need to sum 2 values using the datetime column. Example:

```
Date                Offered
4/16/2012 08:00:00        2
4/16/2012 08:30:00       18
4/16/2012 09:00:00       14
4/16/2012 09:30:30       42
```

I need to sum the values of 08:00:00 with 08:30:00 (total: 20) and 09:00:00 with 09:30:00 (total: 56) and so on.

Comment: Which database are you using? MySql, SQL Server, Oracle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work for you

```
select datepart(hour,myDate), SUM(Offered)
from myTable
group by 
    datepart(hour,myDate), 
    dateadd(d, 0, datediff(d, 0, myDate))
```

You need to group by both the hour and the date if you want it summed by individual day, otherwise you'll include other days (IE April 15 etc...)

Answer (score 2):

Your pseudo code

```
Select HOUR(date), sum(offered) as sumO
FROM YourTable
Group By Hour(date)
```

Hour(date) would need to be altered to the correct syntax for the database you're working with.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [Hour] = DATEPART(HOUR, [Date]), Offered = SUM(Offered)
  FROM dbo.table_name
  WHERE [Date] >= '20120416'
  AND [Date] < '20120417'
  GROUP BY DATEPART(HOUR, [Date])
  ORDER BY [Hour];
```

Comment: I don't think that this is very helpful, because it only works for a single day.

Comment: @Stefan uh, it only works for a single day because that's the date range the example used. You can put any date range there.

Answer (score -1):

Use a DatePart function.
Syntax depends on your database

```
Select DatePart("year", Date), Sum(Offered)
From table1
Group By DatePart("year", Date)
```

Comment: It sounds like he wants to sum by the hour, not by the year.

Comment: Similar concept, but you might want to check if its the same date also

Comment: I would like to be able to do it by hour and make sure that it is the same date as well. Thanks!